# Create Pandas DataFrame from a list and list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have two python lists

```
messages = ['message1', 'message2', 'message3']

labels = [[1,0,1,3,1], [1,1,2,0,3], [0,0,2,1,0]]
```

I am creating dataFrame which will take **messages** as first column and **labels** as **cat_1, cat_2, cat_3, cat_4, cat_5** i.e. total 6 columns

I tried

```
msgs_labels = pd.DataFrame(
{'message': messages,
 'cat': labels,
})
```

but it returns two columns. **messages** and **cat**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If no problem with starting by `0` for new columns names use `DataFrame` constructors with `join`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'message': messages}).join(pd.DataFrame(labels).add_prefix('cat_'))
print (df)
    message  cat_0  cat_1  cat_2  cat_3  cat_4
0  message1      1      0      1      3      1
1  message2      1      1      2      0      3
2  message3      0      0      2      1      0
```

---

```
f = lambda x: f'cat_{x + 1}'
df = pd.DataFrame({'message': messages}).join(pd.DataFrame(labels).rename(columns=f))

print (df)

    message  cat_1  cat_2  cat_3  cat_4  cat_5
0  message1      1      0      1      3      1
1  message2      1      1      2      0      3
2  message3      0      0      2      1      0
```

Some another ideas:

```
f = lambda x: f'cat_{x + 1}'
df = (pd.DataFrame(labels,index=messages)
        .rename(columns=f)
        .rename_axis('messages')
        .reset_index())

print (df)
   messages  cat_1  cat_2  cat_3  cat_4  cat_5
0  message1      1      0      1      3      1
1  message2      1      1      2      0      3
2  message3      0      0      2      1      0
```

Or a bit crazy:

```
f = lambda x: f'cat_{x + 1}'
df = (pd.DataFrame(labels,index=pd.Series(messages, name='messages'))
        .rename(columns=f)
        .reset_index())
```

Or solution with processing nested lists first:

```
d = {f'cat_{i + 1}': x for i, x in enumerate(map(list, zip(*labels)))}
d = {**{'message': messages}, **d}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print (df)
    message  cat_1  cat_2  cat_3  cat_4  cat_5
0  message1      1      0      1      3      1
1  message2      1      1      2      0      3
2  message3      0      0      2      1      0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df=(pd.DataFrame(labels,index=messages)
   .reset_index()
   .rename(columns=lambda x:'cat_'+str(x+1) if x!='index' else 'messages'))
```

Output of `df`:

```
    messages    cat_1   cat_2   cat_3   cat_4   cat_5
0   message1    1       0       1       3       1
1   message2    1       1       2       0       3
2   message3    0       0       2       1       0
```

Comment: @ScottBoston - there is problem with index name

Comment: Thankyou @ScottBoston sir but I can't chain `reset_index()` after `rename()` because I need to rename index as well as mentioned by @jezrael sir

Comment: Yep. I noticed.  Thanks for pointing it out.   You still got my +1

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({i:j for i,j in zip(messages,labels)}).T.add_prefix('cat_').rename_axis('messages',axis=0).reset_index()
```